# Google iOS device policy is not playing nicely with iOS apps using google SSO

Tags: ios, react-native, google-sso

We have built a react-native app that uses Google sign on.
We use `react-native-google-signin` and publish an ios and android app.

Login works 100% of the time in the android app. It works on ios app aswell, except for some organisations using G Suites. For these organisations I get the famous `admin_policy_enforced` error.

[image: policy-enforced]

Where I run the app (simulator or device) doesn't seem to impact the testing, but for the sake of being exhaustive: My ios app is installed on my iphone using flightcenter and we use the autosigining option for Xcode when publishing it.

I managed to reproduce that by playing around with my google organisation's settings:

- I used my organisation which has an Apple Push Certificate.
- ‘Mobile Management’ is enabled with ‘Advanced’ settings for iOS

The fact that I have done the following extra things doesn’t seem to solve it :

- Download the certificate on my device.
- Install the Google Device Policy App
- Whitelisting the app in google admin [1](https://i.ibb.co/HVpYPy3/whitelisting.png).

The signin starts working when the iOS mobile management setting is set to basic.

[image: Mobile Management Setting]

Last point, regarding the scopes, I am using the default ones: email and profile.

I'm happy to add more config or code snippets if needed.

Comment: @marouame Raji, did you get any resolution yet ?

Comment: Nope, haven't got any resolution to this.. 
We ended up asking a change of the setting to basic for that particular account.